# How to make a Linksys to make use of another DHCP to generate IPs

Tags: wireless-router, dhcp

We have a network setup here with Windows Server 2003 machine as our AD, DHCP and domain server. Now I want to connect a Linksys to this network to enable wireless. But I dont want Linksys to act as the DHCP and want it to make use of our already existing DHCP server. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate with : http://superuser.com/questions/27446/setup-linksys-wrt54g-to-use-modems-dhcp-server

Answer (score 2):

On a linksys WRT54G2 go to the router config page, http://192.168.1.1/basic.htm, and half way down look for `DHCP Server: [ ]enable [x]disable` (and don't forget to look for `save settings` way down at the bottom).